# Changing h1 and h2 Text Under 1 Role

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have it so that H1 is 3em line height and H2 is a 2em line height, but I'm not sure how to change each one if they are under the same name tag. How do you change just one line like h1? I can't change the HTML.

HTML:

```
<section class="intro" id="zen-intro">
        <header role="banner">
            <h1>CSS Zen Garden</h1>
            <h2>The Beauty of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Design</h2>
        </header>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
div[role=h1.banner] {
    /*Change the line-height of h1 to 3em*/
   line-height:3em;
}

div[role=h2.banner] {
    /*Change the line-height of h2 to 2em*/
   line-height:2em;
}
```

Comment: You have no css class `banner` in your code snippet. Just a `role="banner"` which is not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like below CSS:

```
header h1{line-height: 3em;}
header h2{line-height: 2em;}
```

you don't need to add class ".header" and no need to change HTML.